# Can I use a costco gift card without being a costco member

Tags: shopping, warehouse-clubs

If I have a Costco gift card, do I need to still register as a Costco member to be able to use it?

Comment: Why aren't you asking Costco this, or [websearching it](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=costco+gift+card+no+membership)?

Comment: Victor, yes, the gift card is a way around the membership issue. It would be pretty bad if I gifted someone $100 card but they had to buy a $40 membership to use it.

Answer (score 3):

No you don't have to be a member to use a gift card:

http://lifehacker.com/the-best-things-you-can-do-at-costco-without-a-membersh-1591680306